# Want to set default value selected in JComboBox populated by enum

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

Below statement in if condition is not working, please provide me some solution that how to set selected item for `JComboBox` which are populated by ENUM.

```
      public enum EbayContryEnum 
        {
        AT    (3),
        AU    (4),
        BE    (5),
        CA    (7),
        CH    (14),
        DE    (11),
        ES    (13),
        FR    (10),
        IE    (2),
        IT    (12),
        NL    (16),
        UK    (15),
        US    (1);
        }
```

for ex:-

```
if(country.equals("FR"))
                      {
                      cbImportCountry.setSelectedItem("FR");
                      }
```

But it's not working..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cbImportCountry.setSelectedItem(EbayContryEnum.FR);`

Comment: If the Value is comming from database then how we will set its the selected values..???

Answer (score 9):

```
cbImportCountry.setSelectedItem(EbayContryEnum.FR);
```

Comment: If the Value is comming from database then how we will set its the selected values..???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not looking for assign the value to the combobox.
You are looking for casting your value to the enum.

You can do this via:

```
EbayContryEnum.valueOf("FR");
```