# How to generate next value in mysql table using java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

In course table my primary key is course_code and it has a pattern like 
"SLIOP-P-001" (SLIOP-SUBJECT INITIAL-NUMBER)

I need to generate SLIOP-P-002 when click the generate button.

Can someone guide me a way to code this?

I have attached my project screen shot.I typed the below records.[image]

I have tried below code. But it doesn't work.

```
private void generate_course_codeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
   String c_code=course_catergory.getSelectedItem().toString();

   if(c_code=="Printing"){ 
       try {

    pst.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO course (course_code)VALUE(?)",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        rs = pst.getGeneratedKeys();

        if (rs.next()) {
            cour_code.setText(rs.getString(1)); 
        }

        }   


   catch(Exception e){
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error occured","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
       }
}
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt? Where are you stuck in the process? If you share your code and describe the problem at hand we can give much more helpful answers.

Comment: This isn't how `getGeneratedKeys` works. For one you are trying to execute an insert with a parameter placeholder without providing a value: that is not going to work. Also it is unlikely that your database is currently generating that code (and if it is: you need to show that code as well)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of an automatic way of creating such a pattern. But one tedious way to generate such a key is as follow:

1. Create a table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE course (
      id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      course_code CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );
   ```
2. Insert an entry for a course_code:

   ```
   PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO course (course_code) VALUES (?)");
   pst.setString(1, "SLIOP-P");
   pst.executeUpdate();
   // close pst
   ```

   This will insert the course_code and generates a new integer value for `id` column what you can use as a suffix (see below).
3. Execute a select query for your desired course_code:

   ```
   PreparedStatement pst2 = connection.prepareStatement("select * from course where course_code = ?");
   pst2.setString(1, "SLIOP-P");  // this is an example; pass anything
   ResultSet rs = pst2.executeQuery();
   String courseCode = null;
   if (rs.next()) {
        courseCode = rs.getString("course_code") + "-" + String.format("%03d", rs.getInt("id"));
   }
   ```
4. Return this course code from your method:

   ```
   return courseCode;
   ```

But if you ask me, the better way is to store all possible course codes in a map; unless there is no a requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. When execute the code it pop ups "Field 'category' doesn't have a default value ". Why am i getting this error?

Comment: While running the program by click on the Generate button.

Comment: But there is no field named `category` in the above SQL. Is it caused by `Course Category` probably?

Comment: Yes. I wrote the code when select the particular selection in combo box and after click on the Generate button the code will generate automatically.                                                                                                                                                                                                     String c_code=course_catergory.getSelectedItem().toString();  if("Multimedia".equals(c_code)){ code }

Comment: I don't know Swing but have you tried to set a default value? The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651149/want-to-set-default-value-selected-in-jcombobox-populated-by-enum) might help.

Comment: Thank you very much again for the help because I got an idea on such situations.